# Dynamic number of fields in Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

So I'm trying to create a base form with `Zend_Form`, which I'm going to somehow map to a model.

The thing is that some properties of the model can have multiple values, for instance tags. One piece of content can have unlimited tags. How can I reflect this in `Zend_Form`. Would some kind of a JS-PHP combo be possible here? (I want people to have a plus sign which lets the add another textbox for a new tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `subform` for the tags
2. Use js to clone html
3. Once form is submitted count number of tags, and adjust form config before validation

Comment: Subforms... didn't know that. Thanks!